# Angular 2 material components selected

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I recentrly started using the material.angular.io components on my app:
https://material.angular.io/components/component/button-toggle

Im seeing in the doc that the `button-toggle` component has an `@Input` property called `selected` that is not setting as selected my button like the disabled property is setting as disabled the other one... I'm doing something wrong?

Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/tGZVAbJZpYDxxmKyPRKg?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation `selected` is listed for `MdButtonToggleGroup`. For `MdButtonToggle`, the property you need to use is `checked`.

I have forked your Plunker and edited to show the tab 'One' is selected/checked, [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MXGJlrv3n4SGCIvW8eoN?p=preview).

Let me know if this fixes your issue :)

Comment: thank you!! can u ask me another question? how can I check the first option found in a loop? https://plnkr.co/edit/tGZVAbJZpYDxxmKyPRKg?p=preview

Comment: Glad it helped! 
Please open a separate question for checking the first option in a loop. Then, it will be easier for other to locate this question. In the mean time, I'll try to find a solution :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288434/angular-2-ngfor-first-last-index-loop