# Angular 2 ngfor first, last, index loop

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to set as default the first occurrence in this example: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tGZVAbJZpYDxxmKyPRKg?p=preview)

getting the following error:

```js
    Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("dButtonToggleGroup">
    <md-button-toggle [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let indicador of indicadores; #first = first" value="indicador.id" [checked]="first">"): ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@35:78
    Parser Error: Unexpected token #, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 31 in [let indicador of indicadores; #first = first] in ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@35:78 ("<md-button-toggle *ngFor="let indicador of indicadores; #first = first" value="indicador.id" [ERROR ->][checked]="first">
    <span>{{ indicado"): ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@35:153
```

what is wrong??

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Check out this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uEst8F6pJgD1V7jZzNxv?p=preview).

When you're binding to variables, you need to use the brackets. Also, you use the hashtag when you want to get references to elements in your html, not for declaring variables inside of templates like that.

```html
<md-button-toggle *ngFor="let indicador of indicadores; let first = first;" [value]="indicador.id" [checked]="first">
```

---

**Edit:**
Thanks to [Christopher Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6806381/christopher-moore):
Angular exposes the following local variables ([documented here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)):

- `index`
- `first`
- `last`
- `even`
- `odd`

Comment: Thank you! that helped me so much, but i tried to use the first because searching about it i found some examples like: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/ (Identifying the first and the last element of a list)

Comment: Ah, ok. You can also do that. Instead of `let i = index`, just change it to `let first = first;` and change the [checked] binding to just check "first" instead of "i == 0".

Comment: nice! now is working! but i cant understand at all why i must bind the checked attribute with brackets

Comment: Because `checked` is an `input`, the binding is required to pass in the value to it. You can read about it more here:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#why-input

Comment: @PriNcee because that's how angular determines you want to bind to a variable. Without the brackets, it just thinks you want to pass a string value into that attribute.

Comment: @Steveadoo in [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) Angular exposes the following local variables `index`, `first`, `last`, `even` and `odd`. Could you update the answer to clarify this point for future users?

Comment: Instead of `let first = first` you can write `first as isFirst` (isFirst is the custom variable) as described here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: can i get last and before last one ?

Comment: How can we toggle to other option if we choose let `first as isFirst;` ? It will always point first index.

Answer (score 96):

Here is how its done in Angular 6

```html
    <li *ngFor="let user of userObservable ; first as isFirst">
       <span *ngIf="isFirst">default</span>
    </li>
```

Note the change from `let first = first` to `first as isFirst`

Comment: ```let first = first``` and ```first as isFirst``` both the declarations are correct to use, second one alias is pretty much readable

Answer (score 26):

**By this you can get any index in `*ngFor` loop in ANGULAR ...**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let object of myArray; let i = index; let first = first ;let last = last;">
    <div *ngIf="first">
       // write your code...
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="last">
       // write your code...
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

We can use these alias in **`*ngFor`**

- **`index`** : `number` : `let i = index` to get all index of object.
- **`first`** : `boolean` : `let first = first` to get first index of object.
- **`last`** : `boolean` : `let last = last` to get last index of object.
- **`odd`** : `boolean` : `let odd = odd` to get odd index of object.
- **`even`** : `boolean` : `let even = even` to get even index of object.

Comment: How can we toggle to other option if we choose `let first as isFirst;` ? It will always point first index.

Comment: @optimistrohit you can add multiple available variables for a single directive, like first for first element, last for the last one

Comment: I need to display a button only for the last Id and this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, last does not work if there are many database entries to be displayed by ngFor.  If you add {{last}} to the item that is being listed so that you can see its contents, you will see that every so often, last is true and then changes to false.  When the actual last item is shown, last is shown as true and all the others above are shown as false.  This means that "last" is true even though the last item is not shown.