# How to show 'Edit' link followed by last list item using Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

List is populating dynamically and width of each list text might vary ..it is small to larger text as well. Here I would like to display 'Edit' link should display after the last list item. Here is the sample code I tried

```
<ul
  class=""
  *ngIf=""
>
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="">
    <li *ngFor="let emppData of getEmpData(); let i = index; let test = test11123">
      <span class="day-label">{{ emppData.day }}</span>
      <span *ngIf="emppData.emppData">{{ emppData.empLabel }}</span>
    </li>
     <li *ngIf="isTaestable$ | async">
      <button
        id="idTestButton"
        [disabled]="false"
        buttonSize="md"
        buttonStyle="link"
        aria-label="Edit"
        (click)="testEmpData()"
      >
        {{ edit }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Sample output:

```
Sunday AAAA
Monday BBBB
Tuesday CCC. 'Edit'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `*ngFor` variables. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288434/angular-2-ngfor-first-last-index-loop)

Additional details from [Maxime Chevallier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6275132/maxime-chevallier):

To complete the answer, the let last = last in the *ngFor is a boolean given by Angular that is true when the element is the last element of the array. [reference](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)

```
<ul
  class=""
  *ngIf=""
>
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="">
    <li *ngFor="let emppData of getEmpData(); let i = index; let test = test11123;let last = last;">
      <span class="day-label">{{ emppData.day }}</span>
      <span *ngIf="emppData.emppData">{{ emppData.empLabel }}</span>
    </li>
     <li *ngIf="isTaestable$ | async">
      <button
        *ngIf="last"
        id="idTestButton"
        [disabled]="false"
        buttonSize="md"
        buttonStyle="link"
        aria-label="Edit"
        (click)="testEmpData()"
      >
        {{ edit }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Comment: To complete the answer, the `let last = last` in the `*ngFor` is a boolean given by Angular that is `true` when the element is the last element of the array. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: Thanks @NarenMurali, actually. here...I'm able to display all list items one by one...but I need to display 'Edit' link immediately after the last list item. I tried to add the the solution above, but Edit link is completely last visible in the UI.

Comment: @Rajasekhar Use CSS to make the edit link come at the bottom of the table

Answer (score 0):

Add last declaration. As you have done with let=index, you can declare all the following vars:
index
first
last
even
odd

So your code should work with:

```
<ul
  class=""
  *ngIf=""
>
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="">
    <li *ngFor="let emppData of getEmpData(); 
        let i = index; 
        let test = test11123;
        let last = last">
      <span class="day-label">{{ emppData.day }}</span>
      <span *ngIf="emppData.emppData">{{ emppData.empLabel }}</span>
    </li>
     <li *ngIf="isTaestable$ | async">
      <button *ngIf="last"
        id="idTestButton"
        [disabled]="false"
        buttonSize="md"
        buttonStyle="link"
        aria-label="Edit"
        (click)="testEmpData()"
      >
        {{ edit }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

Check other questions with your same issue:
[Angular 2 ngfor first, last, index loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288434/angular-2-ngfor-first-last-index-loop)