# angular check first index on the template

Tags: angular, typescript

we can check the last index of the loop in the template using 'last' like the example below

but how do we check on the template for the first index  ? like for example I only want to show the paragraph on the first index

```
 <div *ngFor="let p of history; last as l" fxLayout="row"
       <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: kindlt post this as answer Sir so I can upvote you.

Comment: Hi , It's already answered in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288434/angular-2-ngfor-first-last-index-loop, Hence I am closing this as duplicate.