# I am trying to compare value 1 to a value within the previous object while using *ngFor

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to compare 2 entries within an *ngFor loop. The code should be comparing the value at the current object to a value at the previous object in the loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of s_1.comments[0]; index as b">

              <article class="message is-small is-size-6" >
             <div class="header {{item.type}}">
                    {{item.type | stringyfy:'_' | titlecase}} <div class="text">{{item.mood}}</div>
                  </div>
                <div class="body" *ngFor="let comment of item.comments">
                  {{comment.text}}      </div>
              </article>

          <article class="message " *ngIf="b > 0 && item.rating > item[b-1].rating;">
              <div class="message-header">
              </div>
              <div class="message-body" >
                  Mood All Year
              </div>
          </article>

</ng-container>
```

I am using `*ngIf` to conditionally show data based on the result. In this situation if the Rating is higher than the Rating of the previous entry.

This is where the error comes up has something to do with the fact I am subtracting 1 from b.

```
          <article class="message " *ngIf="b >= 1 && item.rating > item[b-1].rating;">
              <div class="message-header">
              </div>
              <div class="message-body" >
                  Mood All Year
              </div>
          </article>
```

---

What is the problem now?

I get an error in the console saying that **`item_r86[(b_r87 - 1)]` is undefined**. I believe it has something to do with the -1.

Comment: Similar to index, ngFor has a first property, check that in your logic before index accessing the previous array member. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288434/angular-2-ngfor-first-last-index-loop

Comment: You can try to check b > 0 in the ngIf -> *ngIf="b > 0 && item.rating > s_1.comments[b-1].rating"

Comment: Please. Do check the Edit on the question. I rewrote the code because the Iteration stopped. Now I get the same issue just on a different part. `<article class="message "*ngIf="b > 0 && item.rating > item[b-1].rating;"><div class="message-header"></div><div class="message-body" >Mood All Year</div></article>`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your index `[b-1]` will be -1 for b=0 in `*ngIf="item[b].rating > s_1.comments[b-1].rating"`. So you have to think about the edge cases of your solution: What do you want to compare your first element with? Or do you want to show it, if there is nothing to compare it to, because there is no previous element?

I would implement the desired behaviour in a typescript function that gets the index and returns a boolean and use it inside the *ngIf:

```
*ngIf="showElementXYZ(b)"
```

Comment: that's very true.

Comment: Check the question again. I have the same issue when i make a minor alteration

Comment: Well, you are still doing the same mistake. `*ngIf="b >= 1 && item.rating > item[b-1].rating;"` is still checking for an array-element on index -1 which does not exist. So, I keep my answer: write the (eventually complex) logic you want to achieve inside a typescript function. It will be easier and more maintainable.

Comment: That is not the issue, this time around. The issue seems to be the indexing. I changed the syntax.

Comment: The only change that I see is, that you added `b >= 1 &&` --> but that does not change the behaviour as angular checks both sides of the `&&` if they are true and does not abort the action if the first is false.

Comment: No I changed the whole codebase. Lookagain `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of s_1.comments[0]; index as b">`

Comment: I cannot understand, what your change may help. I only see that your index is b and that you still try to call the value of item[b-1]. As the index b will also be 0 inside of the loop you are trying to call the value of the item at position -1 which will not exist in an array.

Comment: I get your point, How do I fix the issue ?

Comment: Man... are you trolling around? --> Look at my answer above: I would implement the desired behaviour in a typescript function that gets the index and returns a boolean and use it inside the *ngIf:

`*ngIf="showElementXYZ(b)"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255535/discussion-between-tom-and-allforthenoob).

Answer (score 0):

I have a found a better solution.

The comparisons did not work until I made a duplicate of the array and added an extra entry to the start with `unshift()` . That ensured that the arrays will have a different value at each index.