# In an *ngFor loop - How can I access a value from the previous object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

The data looks like this

```
s_1.comments = [{"rating": 1},{"rating": 3},{"rating": 2},{"rating": 4},{"rating": 2}]

arr_1 = [
[{"rating": 1},{"rating": 3},{"rating": 2},{"rating": 4},{"rating": 2}]
]
```

I am trying to compare 2 entries within an *ngFor loop. The code should be comparing the value at the current object to a value at the previous object in the loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of s_1.comments[0]; index as b">

              <article class="message" >
             <div class="header {{item.type}}">
                    {{item.type | stringyfy:'_' | titlecase}} <div class="text">{{item.mood}}</div>
                  </div>
                <div class="body" *ngFor="let comment of item.comments">
                  {{comment.text}}      </div>
              </article>

          <article class="message " *ngIf="s1.comments.length > 0 && arr_1[0].rating > arr_1[0][b-1].rating;">
              <div class="header">
              </div>
              <div class="body" >
                  Mood All Year
              </div>
          </article>

</ng-container>
```

I am using `*ngIf` to conditionally show data based on the result. In this situation if the Rating is higher than the Rating of the previous entry.

```
          <article class="message " *ngIf="s1.comments.length > 0 && arr_1[0].rating > arr_1[0][b-1].rating;">
              <div class="header">
              </div>
              <div class="body" >
                  Mood All Year
              </div>
          </article>
```

---

The behavior I am expecting is that "Mood All Year" Will be added ever so often, turn out it never does. The code works though.

Whats wrong with this?

.......

Angular renders the page,and no errors pops up in console. So the code is good. The problem is the conditions never returns True. I believe it has something to do with the comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to compare value 1 to a value within the previous object while using \*ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77238209/i-am-trying-to-compare-value-1-to-a-value-within-the-previous-object-while-using)

Comment: It does'nt . The answer only told me what I was doing wrong and not how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure the code is working? You have `item.rating` which shows that `items` is an object, but then you compare it to `item[b-1].rating` which suggests that the `item` is array of objects. Something's not right there.

Comment: Yes I am looking at the project right now. It works. Item is the alias for an array of objects s_1.comments[0] (needs index to access). Item would already be at a particular object in the loop - so it's a bit obvious item[b-1] is wrong. But it does not break the code. SO something works.

Comment: Consider moving the complex logic into your component's typescript code. Maybe have a separate view model property that includes the other properties from each item, plus a boolean or enum to represent whether that item represents an upward/downward trend. That'll make it easy to unit test your logic, and allow the template code to focus on how to represent that model in HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of small issues in your code. For example

1. *ngFor="let item of s_1.comments[0]

Here s_1.comments[0] returns a single object and not an array. So running ngFor on a single object does not make sense

2. *ngIf="b > 0 && item.rating > item[b-1].rating;"

   Here item[b-1] does not make sense since item is a single object of an array.

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gphhno?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with a small section of your code. I hope this is what you expect. If you have any question feel free to ask. Please make sure you mark it as answer if it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I changed the mistake a bit. The app renders in the browser. I have no clue why it never returns true. No matter if i change > to < or == . Simply baffled !

Comment: I would suggest you to create a stackblitz with just the necessary code. It will be easier for other developers to look and tweak. Also if you can check whether there is any error/warning in console

Comment: thought that too. Will do in a bit